# If $A=B+C$, $BC=CB$ and $AD=DA$, does $BD=DB$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ are $n\times n$ matrices s.t. $A=B+C$, $B$ and $C$ commute and $A$ and $D$ commute, do $B$ and $D$ have to commute? Saw this used in another proof and it sounded like this was trivial but I tried proving it and I couldn't. Thanks.

Comment: Not necessarily unless $C$ also commutes with $D$.

Comment: Can you find a counterexample?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $A:=I$ and $B$ and $D$ being arbitrary matrices that do not commute.  Then $C=I-B$.  Clearly, $A$ and $D$ commute, and it can easily be seen that $B(I-B)=(I-B)B$, so $B$ and $C$ commute.  Since the hypotheses are true and the result is false, the implication must be false.

Answer (score 0):

Just repeating Jack's comment but it's too big for a comment:

Start with $A = B + C$ and multiply through by $D$ on the left to get $$DA = DB + DC \:.$$ Now repeat but multiply through by $D$ on the right to get $$AD = BD + CD \:.$$ Subtract one result from the other: $$\left(DA - AD\right) = \left(DB - BD\right) + \left(DC - CD\right)$$

The left side is given as zero, and the right side is only zero if we simultaneously have: $$DB = BD \hspace{2.54cm} DC = CD$$

... what has not been explicitly used yet is $BC=CB$.